# React Native - Switch not changing value

Tags: ios, react-native

Currently my code is leaving whatever default value I put into the Switch and not changing it. The onValueChange is fired and I get the correct value from, but no matter what I do, the switch moves and goes back to the default position, like nothing updated the state.

The main code I want to use is this one:

```
 <Switch style={styles.select} value={this.state.banks[rowData.code].status} onValueChange={(newValue) => this.saveValue(rowData,newValue)}/>


saveValue = (rowData,newValue) => {
    //var row = rowData[Object.keys(rowData)[0]];
    rowData.status = newValue;
    this._sh.set('@Banks:'+rowData.code,newValue.toString()).then(
      (result) => {
        this._banks[rowData.code].status = newValue;
        this.setState({
          banks: this._banks
        });
      }
    );
    return newValue;
  }
```

At first I thought it was a very complex state scenario so I also tried just using the Switch outside the row and inside a  regular view (instead of a datasource). I also tried using a default implementation as you see in the documentation examples of Switch and also, does not work.

I am trying over an iPhone 6s simulator and a real 5s device. Still same behavior.

I am about to think this is a bug in RN but haven't found anything related and I am losing my mind because this is supposed to be very easy.

Eventually, what I have is a JSON file with a list of banks where the user can select if the want that enabled or not, and I am using that array to store the values and make the Switch get the status from there. _sh is a StorageHelper wrapper from AsyncStorage, but I also removed that part from the code and still the same issue.

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll be dammed it was because I have it inside a ListView and I was updating the same object and not creating a copy. This code works:

```
saveValue = (rowData,newValue) => {
    //var row = rowData[Object.keys(rowData)[0]];
    var banksAux = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.banks));

    rowData.status = newValue;
    this._sh.set('@Banks:'+rowData.code,newValue.toString()).then(
      (result) => {
        banksAux[rowData.code].status = newValue;
        this.setState({
          banks: banksAux,
          dsBanks: this.state.dsBanks.cloneWithRows(banksAux)
        });
      }
    );
    return newValue;
  }
```

Very ugly but apparently I did some research and is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I had been stuck on this problem for days.